# Array Values from Text or CSV File in Shell

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, loops, for-loop

I am having a script in which I am declaring arrays like below:

```
declare -a Pool=("Terrace|HouseTerrace_")
declare -a Library=("lib1 lib2 lib3")
declare -a Name=("Guru/Raju Albert Deepak")
declare -a Email=("Guru@american.com,Raju@american.com Albert@american.com Deepak@amaerican.com")
Sub=("Media Rotation")
i=0
while [ $i -lt ${#Pool[@]}  ]
do
command blah balh blah
i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

Now what i want is that instead of declaring values in aaray here i should import it from file (either text or csv ) or is there any better way perfroming this task. I don want to give access to script file to users.

Comment: Look into the `mapfile` bash builtin.

Comment: @GURUSINGH: I don't understand what you are going to do here, all five of your 'arrays' consist of a single element only, so what's the point in declaring them as arrays?

Comment: @ user1934428 I am novice.give me better way..

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer, to help kick-start the OP effort.

The bash "readarray" can be used to load an array from a file. For example they code `declare -a email=("a@a.com" "b@b.com" ...)` can be replaced with

```
readarray email < email.txt
```

Where email.txt is (using posted data)

```
Guru@american.com
Raju@american.com
Albert@american.com
...
```

Another suggest improvement will be to use `for item in` instead of `while` loops to iterate over arrays. Instead of `i=0 ; while [ $i -lt ${#Pool[@]}  ] ; do ... ; done`

```
for p in "${pool[@]}" ; do
   command $p
done
```

Comment: Thanks, Dash-o but my requirement is that for Pool "Terrace", select Library "lib1",  select the name  "Guru/Raju" and drop a mail to "Guru@american.com,Raju@american.com". and again then second pool name,second lib,second name ...this way.It's like pick every first argument from each array and run the script.

Comment: The answer is giving you a template as the requirement are not very detailed. If you need a specific entry to include multiple lines with comma separator, put that line into the text file. I strongly suggest that you will read one of the 'intro to bash programming' documents.